# How to change default permissions on Jenkins workspace directory on fedora?

Tags: linux, jenkins

I have a mysql instance that needs to dump csv files into a jenkins workspace. Unfortunately, Jenkins has permissions 755 for the workspace directory, and I need to be able to create and delete jobs of this type very often, so manual configuration doesn't work. How do I change the default permissions on these directories without writing a script do do it?

Comment: Is the MySQL instance running as a job in Jenkins or is it an external process outside of Jenkins which just copies file in the workspace? Who is the owner of workspace directory? Is the MySQL running with the same owner?

Comment: the MySQL instance is a separate process running under the user mysql. i've added the mysql user to the jenkins group, manually changed permissions to 775, and it still doesn't work. I have a separate web server that needs to be able to access this database. Should I run the web server under the Jenkins user?

Comment: I believe its a problem with the database, it doesn't seem to be able to write anywhere. Is there something I have to do besides running grant file? I'm on Fedora 20.

Comment: We changed the `umask` for the `jenkins` user, but that doesn't seem to work. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: It was a long time ago, but I think I ended up having mysql write to a buffer folder and then have the Jenkins job pick up the files. It was a completely hacked up solution, but it worked.

Answer (score -2):

Just change the permissions on the root workspace directory.  The workspaces for each job will be in subdirectories underneath the root, so they will inherit the root directory's permissions.

```
chown -R jenkins_user:jenkins_group /path_to_workspace_root
```

Comment: Thanks. However, when I create a new job, will jenkins create folders with the new permissions?

Comment: Works for me: `sudo chown -R username:jenkins workspace_path/`