# How to change default permissions of created jobs in Jenkins file system

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

When I create a job(say foo), if I check the /jobs/ directory all the jobs are created with the permission 755. But for my use case, when job is created, I want it to created with the 775(or with a given permission). How can I achieve that?. 
Appreciate your help..

Comment: Did you have a look to this solution?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25655000/how-to-change-default-permissions-on-jenkins-workspace-directory-on-fedora

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to change the `umask` value of the jenkins user. When ever jenkins creates a folder it will then create it with the value set in `umask`.

Say the jenkins is running as user `juser` then, in the `bashrc` of the `juser` you will have to add the value `umask 002` to achieve the folder permission as `775`

Also, check this post --- [Setting the umask of the jenkins process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517348/setting-the-umask-of-the-jenkins-process)